# How to capture XRDS document provided by google while implementing OpenId using java servlets

Tags: java, openid, google-oauth, google-openid

I was trying to implement OpenId in Java using google Openid provider. I read that we need to do `response.sendRedirect()`

This gives me an XML document in return, meaning it asks me to save a XRDS document. I do not know how to handle this document in the servlet. It would be great help if someone addresses this simple issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're aware of [openid4java](https://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) - it's an openid library and it should have the functionality you're looking for. Whether you decide to use this or not, take a look at the [sample consumer code](https://code.google.com/p/openid4java/wiki/SampleConsumer), it should provide you with an idea of how to retrieve and parse the XRDS yourself if you decide not to use the library.

For example with the openid4java library, you can get the Google endpoint with something as simple as:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager;
import org.openid4java.discovery.DiscoveryException;
import org.openid4java.discovery.DiscoveryInformation;

public class XRDSConsumer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConsumerManager manager = new ConsumerManager();
    try {
      //get XRDS from Google discovery url
      List<DiscoveryInformation> discoveries = 
          manager.discover("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id");

      for(DiscoveryInformation info: discoveries) {
        //will get something like: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
        System.out.println(info.getOPEndpoint());
      }
    } catch (DiscoveryException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. will try this and let u knw, if the issue is fixed.. and I've got a question for you.., is openId4java a third party library?

Comment: I am forced not to use third party libraries for my project. So do we have any other way with out using it. I have implemented the later steps required for OpenId implementation (like appending the open end point URI to the URL below and have done response.sendRedirect(newconfiguredURL))

Comment: And am getting the response back with the requested email and language

Comment: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
&openid.ns.pape=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0
&openid.ns.max_auth_age=300
&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.return_to=http://www.example.com/checkauth
&openid.realm=http://www.example.com/ ...along with the exchange attributes.. Am unable to paste the whole thing..  Thanks for your prompt replies